# How to extract project from BIRT report designer into a WAR file

Tags: birt

I am very new to Eclipse BIRT. I saw some tutorials online and built a small report application inside the Eclipse Birt report designer which can be downloaded online and comes with its own eclipse.
My question is how to I export this project as a WAR file and deploy it in an application server like Open Liberty and run it so that I can call it from my actual web application.